# Value Not Binding In Edit Item Template Dropdown Field When Click Edit Button In Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have item template, edit item template, footer template for add, edit update records,

when i am inserting there is no problem,
when i am click edit button for update, its not bind my item template value in edit item template field.

Note : there is no problem in text box binding, the problem is not binding in dropdownlist.

Is there any possblities to bind  like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="130px" CssClass="dropdown" 
DataTextField='<%# Eval("StatusName")%>'>
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--SELECT--"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="NIL"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="NOT YET TAKEN"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="WORK IN PROGRESS"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="COMPLETED"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="UNDER TESTING"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="NOT POSSIBLE"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

like text box :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStatusName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StatusName")%>' 
CssClass="textbox" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void gvwTask_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gvwTask.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            Fill();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }


protected void gvwTask_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gvwTask.EditIndex = -1;
            Fill();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

Fill():

```
public void Fill()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsTask = new DataSet("tblTask");
            dsTask = bolTask.SelectAllTask();
            if (dsTask.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                
                gvwTask.DataSource = dsTask.Tables[0];
                gvwTask.DataBind();
                            
            }
            else
            {
                gvwTask.DataSource = null;
                gvwTask.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

give me the solution!..

[image: INITIAL GRIDVIEW]
[image]

Comment: Post the code for your `Fill()` method

Comment: i edit & posted just now in the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblStatusName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StatusName")%>' CssClass="label"
                                                        Width="130px"></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>                                                       
     <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StatusID")%>' Visible = "false"></asp:Label>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="130px" CssClass="dropdown">
         <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--SELECT--"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="NIL"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="NOT YET TAKEN"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="WORK IN PROGRESS"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="COMPLETED"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="UNDER TESTING"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="NOT POSSIBLE"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="HOLD"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>                                      
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="130px" CssClass="dropdown">
         <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--SELECT--"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="NIL"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="NOT YET TAKEN"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="WORK IN PROGRESS"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="COMPLETED"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="UNDER TESTING"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="NOT POSSIBLE"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="HOLD"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
 </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

c# Code :

```
protected void gvwTask_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {    
           if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvwTask.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {
                DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlStatus");
                Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
                string t = lblStatus.Text;
                ddlStatus.SelectedValue = t;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

During every edit command you need to bind items collection to the dropdown (seems currently happening in your Fill() method?) and than set the SelectedValue property to show selected item to user during editing.
Suppose the name of dropdown is ddlWorkStatus than see this code sample

```
protected void gvwTask_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        gvwTask.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        Fill();
        var id = Convert.ToInt64(e.Keys[0]); // you need to set DataKeyNames attribute to receive identifier of selected row item in code behind. 
        var ddlWorkStatus = gvwTask.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlWorkStatus") as DropDownList;
        if(ddlWorkStatus != null)
        {
            //var fetchedObject = queried object based on id;
            ddlWorkStatus.SelectedValue = fetchedObject.StatusProperty;
        } 
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error Message", "alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "')", true);
    }
}
```